# Restrict deployment to certain environments based on version tag

Tags: deployment, tfs, versioning, octopus-deploy

I'm finalising my CI setup with TFS and I have one last part to overcome. Currently, every CI build is pushed to octopus with the nuget packages versioned as major.minor.patch.buildid, and these are used in releases in Octopus versioned as major.minor.patch-beta{buildid}. Therefore, every CI build will be tagged as a beta build for a given release, e.g. 1.3.0.194 / 1.3.0-beta194. There will no doubt be a number of iterative dev builds before one is chosen to go to the test team - let's assume the chosen build is 194 in this case. At this point I envisage the creation of a new build, 1.3.0-rc1, which uses the build 194 binaries. This is then pushed to the test environment and testing begins. There may be a number of testing cycles, so let's say the testers sign off the version 1.3.0-rc4. A new release could then be made, 1.3.0, based on the 1.3.0-rc4 binaries, which is the gold release for the product.

Firstly, is this a good idea? Some feedback would be much appreciated.

Seperately, is it possible to restrict deployments to certain environments based on a tag in the version? In my example, I would never want a release marked as -beta to be deployed to a test environment - only -rc builds should be. Likewise, only tag-less builds should be deployed to production environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the reason why you definitely shouldn't do that.

When you create version 1.3.0.194, Octopus will guarantee that the artefacts, process, and variables are given a snap-shot that means the deployment will performed in the same way on every environment.

You can edit these things as much as you like, but 1.3.0.194 will not become a more risky deployment due to these changes, as it will be oblivious to them.

If you created version 1.3.0.194, then made changes to your deployment process, or variables, these changes would leak into the version `1.3.0.194-beta` and it would no longer be the same deployment that you have tested. The same would occur when you change to version `1.3.0.194-rc` - more changes would leak in that you haven't actually tested.

Your deployment process, just like your code, should be versioned and tested - and that is what you get by using the same version throughout your deployment lifecycle.

Comment: Excellent point about the snapshots Octopus makes of your deployment process and variables etc., versioning the deployment process is just as important as the code.

Answer (score 1):

Tagging **deployment** packages with beta/rc is a bad idea because this introduces an extra step in your delivery process.  You will have many built versions some will advance to upper environments, some won't.  That's okay.  Your trying to treat these like regular Nuget packages used for dependency versioning/management.  Its different.  Just increment your build numbers without the tags and promote the builds that get sign off.

You shouldn't restrict deployments to environment based on tags either.